# PHP Updating Array of Appointments Slots

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of appointments for a day. There are 10 available appointments 15 minutes apart (I'm referring to each 15 minute appointment as a slot) and the list might look like this:

```
 1  Unavailable
 2  Unavailable
 3  Available
 4  Available
 5  Available
 6  Available
 7  Available
 8  Available
 9  Unavailable
 10 Unavailable
```

There are certain types of appointments that require a minimum number of slots. For example if the appointment type is "long" it needs 3 consecutive slots. So in the above example the possible combinations could be

```
 3  Available
 4  Available
 5  Available
```

or

```
 4  Available
 5  Available
 6  Available
```

or

```
 5  Available
 6  Available
 7  Available
```

or

```
 6  Available
 7  Available
 8  Available
```

I then need to update the list to make 7 and 8 unavailable:

```
 7  Unavailable
 8  Unavailable
```

as the appointment cannot start at these times as there are not 3 consecutive available slots starting at these times.

I'm completely stumped as to the logic/rule I can use to implement here? I'm hoping there is something abstract that I can use and just feed in the number of slots required.

Comment: Your explaination is a bit confusing, I loose you at 'keeping 3/4/5 but swap 7/8'. It seems you are asking how to intelligently move appointments around (with code) to maximise the number of appointments in a day. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry - I've just edited the question to hopefully make it more clear. I'm really only concerned with ensuring the the starting times are "available" as long as there are the required number of consecutive slots starting at these times, otherwise I need to change any "available" to "unavailable"

Comment: OK so why are you avoiding using (1-2 and 9-10)? If you have no bookings then a 3 slot appointment can live in 1-3,2-4,3-6,4-7,5-8,6-9. Before you apply any appointments you need to prepare your logic. What is the function of the list and how will it be populated etc.

Comment: As Mathieu says is is a straightforward task, you just need to lookahead to find the right number of 'Availables'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple textbook exercise of a function within a function.

Your first function needs to scan for the first available slot and then passes on the context to the second function that will look ahead from the current position and make sure the next 1/2/3/4/etc slots are available.

If available, the second function returns true, the first function just takes into account that it needs 1/2/3/4/5/etc slots so one possible choice is to use:

- 3/4/5
- 4/5/6
- 5/6/7
- 6/7/8

Note: You can use 1 single function with two imbricated loops and an $i, $k index. I prefer two functions for the sake of simplify and readability!